# Infinite loop till key pressed

Tags: c, loops

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int a=1;
    char c;
    x:for(a=1;a!=0;a++)
    {
        printf("Hello\n");
        c=getch();
        if(c=='n')
            exit(0);
        else
            goto x;
    }
}
```

//please assist me with this program by using primary operators only

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Please take note of compiler warnings: you have missed `#include <stdlib.h>` and `#include <conio.h>`.

Comment: it just wait ,to press a key i want it to print infinite times and end when i pressed the fixed key char in this case 'n' :).

Comment: Then have a look at `kbhit()` function. When it returns non-0, you can then call `getch` non-blocking.

Comment: sir,i tried using it ,but didn't worked out (this was question asked me in my test couple of days back we have not yet taught the kbhit() function  and i'm pretty sure the teacher didn't want us to do it that way) is there any else way we have been taught  getch,putchar,getche function. Thanks for your time:)

Comment: Not unless you can find a way to change keyboard input to non-blocking, which I suspect you won't be expected to do. If you have `conio` then `kbhit` is provided exactly for your needs.

Comment: Your additional requirement in comments is unclear: do you want `Hello` to be printed infinite times while the program is waiting for a key to be pressed?

Comment: Thanks you very much :) vane and anon

Comment: This is not possible with the standard C library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little different, to show you a simple solution. But if you are not allowed to use `kbhit` you are stuck.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>              // include the library header

int main(void)                  // correct signature for main
{
    int c = 0;                  // note getch() returns `int` type
    while(c != 'n')             // until correct key is pressed
    {
        do {                    // forever
            printf("Hello\n");
        } while(!kbhit());      // until a key press detected
        c = getch();            // fetch that key press
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Remember, it only tests for lower-case `n`.

Comment: while(!kbhit()) what does this "!" means

Comment: It means `while(kbhit() == 0)`. The `!` is a boolean `NOT` operator. In other words, not true, in this case true is any non-zero value which is returned by `kbhit()` when a key is waiting to be read. In C, any non-0 value is implicitly true, and 0 is false.

Answer (score 1):

the posted code does not compile!

The following code will do the job.

Notice that the `goto` is eliminated

Notice that the unneeded variables are eliminated

Notice that the appropriate header files are included

Notice the signature for the main() function is corrected

```
#include <stdio.h> // printf()
#include <conio.h> // getch() kbhit() <-- use correct header file

int main( void )          // <-- use valid signature
{
                          // <-- eliminate unneeded variables
    while(1)              // <-- non-confusing (and simple) loop statement
    {
        printf("Hello\n");

        if( kbhit() )
        { // then some key has been pressed
            if( 'n' == getch() )
            { // then 'n' key has been pressed
                break;        // <-- exit the loop
            }
        }
    }
} // end function: main
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main(void) {
    char c='y';
    while(c!='n') {
        while(!kbhit()) {
            printf("Hello\n");
        }
        c=getch();
    }
}
```

Please note that I have not compiled this as *conio.h* is not available to me right now.